# Turn transferUserInfo into sendMessage

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I've currently got my data being **passed from the iPhone to the Watch using `transferUserInfo`**.

I would like to **add an additional function to ask the iPhone for the same data (immediately since it could be the first time the Watch is opened) from the Watch**.

So I would **need`sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:`, but I can't figure out** how to use it.

(*What I have with `transferUserInfo`:*)

**iPhone `TableViewController.swift`**:

```
let applicationDict = ["TC" : newP.tC, "Mat" : newP.mat]
let transfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferUserInfo(applicationDict)
```

**Watch `InterfaceController.swift`**:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let tC = userInfo["TC"] as? String, let mat = userInfo["Mat"] as? String {

        receivedData.append(["TC" : tC , "Mat" : mat])
        ExtensionDelegate.evnts.append(Evnt(dataDictionary: ["TC" : tC , "Mat" : mat]))
        doTable()

    } else {
        print("tC and mat are not same as dictionary value")
    }

}
```

(*What I have tried adding with `sendMessage`:*)

**iPhone `TableViewController.swift`**:

```
                let msg = WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(applicationDict, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
```

**Watch `InterfaceController.swift`**:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    //handle received message
    let value1 = message["TC"] as? String
    let value2 = message["Mat"] as? String

    //use this to present immediately on the screen
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //self.messageLabel.setText(value)
        print("ValWatch1: \(value1)")
        print("ValWatch2: \(value2)")

    }
    //send a reply
    replyHandler(["TC":"Yes"])

}
```

*I can't tell what all I have messed up.*

Comment: Merely changing the method call is not sufficient.  You should watch a WWDC video or find a good Watch Connectivity tutorial that explains what you need to do for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying to send a message to the watch is correct

```
let msg = WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(applicationDict, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
```

But are you sure the watch is paired? you may need to add this check first before sending the message

```
if (WCSession.defaultSession().reachable) {
 // send message 
}
```

Also make sure your watch app is running while you are trying to send the message from your parent app. If your watch app is not in the foreground, then it wouldn't receive the message sent from your iphone app.

Comment: Good information, but you answered a different question. If you look at the second paragraph, the OP apparently wants someone to write the code for the watch to ask the phone for data.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was missing!